# Error initializing JRE. Flash CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Recently I have been getting this error:

> Error initializing Java Runtime Environment. You may need to reinstall Flash.

It pops up when I try to compile my swf.

ScreenShot: http://prntscr.com/abwror

[image]

I deleted the .ini file in appdata but it didn't fix the problem.

I'm using windows 7 64bit, flash cc, just running the swf inside flash (ctrl + enter), yes im using the oracle version.

Comment: What operating system are you using? How are you compiling your Flash? What version of Java are you using? Are you using the Oracle version? (Please edit your question with the new information, thanks).

Comment: Before writing a question, please follow the tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i'm using windows 7 64bit, flash cc, just running the swf inside flash (ctrl + enter), yes im using the oracle version